# How to check if a user already exists in firebase during phone auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to  create an app that only uses phone authorization from firebase. Since the login/signup is done through same process, which is verifying the sent code. How can i check if a user already exists in firebase? I need this to show them appropriate User Interface.

Comment: I don't get the question to be honest. If the user is already logged in its clear what to do. If he opens the app new and is not logged in he in any case needs to reenter his phone number in order to authenticate. So there is no real difference in-between. You need to know his credentials(eg his Phone Number) to know if he exists. But if he provides the number you can just immediately log him in?

Comment: Lets say a user launched the app for the first time and signed up by verifying his number. He is then presented with the activity which inquires name/email etc to complete the registration (Let's call it X). When he logs out, he has to re-authenticate by going through the same phone verifying process next time he wants to use the app. However this time he shouldn't be shown the X activity right? That's where the problem is. Since I have no way to find out if this is a new user or already registered, I don't know how can I skip the X activity for those who are simply logging in.

Comment: Are you going to create users? What permissions are you going to grant them? And to create users your application needs pretty high permissions which is bad for security, because if you make a mistake you can loos your whole database of all your bases if you have many.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now, the only way to do that is via the Firebase Admin SDK. There is an API to [lookup a user by phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data).

```
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // User found.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this looks like legit method. I was trying to figure out things on my own while waiting for a reply and decided to check if user's data already exists on firestore cloud and it worked well.

Comment: @bojeil I'm confused where to put this serviceAccountKey.json file and  then set it's path ,i'm  using android studio

Comment: Do not use Admin SDK API in your android app. This should only run from a secure server. Service accounts should never be exposed to the client, otherwise, your users and their data would be compromised.

Comment: @bojeil I have the same question. If we don't use the admin SDK in our app, how will we be able to check if a phone account already exists? I'm confused where we run this code if not in the app.

Comment: @Karen you can run it as a hosted function and make an API call to it from your app. That way you only expose the singular function to your app and not the whole admin sdk

Answer (score 6):

You can check whether user already exist in Firebase by compare it metadata. see code example:

```
PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, smsCode);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(PhoneLoginEnterCodeActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task){
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        long creationTimestamp = user.getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp();
                        long lastSignInTimestamp = user.getMetadata().getLastSignInTimestamp();
                        if (creationTimestamp == lastSignInTimestamp) {
                            //do create new user
                        } else {
                           //user is exists, just do login
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an `additionalUserInfo` property that you can query like so (Kotlin):

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener {
        it.result.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser // new user check
    }
```

If I borrow @Eltanan Derek code:

```
PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, smsCode);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential).addOnCompleteListener(PhoneLoginEnterCodeActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task){
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser().getAdditionalUserInfo();
                        
                        if (user.isNewUser()) {
                            //do create new user
                        } else {
                           //user is exists, just do login
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```