# How to check if a user phone number exists using firebase auth?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app where i prompt the user to authenticate with their phone number in the first place. if the user phone number doesn't already exist he's redirected to a page with username and password. **IF** he exists, he's prompted to the password page directly.

How i can check if the user phone number already exists (or not) before knowing which page he will be sent?

i did check the docs, i found this solution

```
getAuth()
  .getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log(`Successfully fetched user data:  ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

But i need to it run in a backend server. What i want is something similar but that i will use in the front ( i'm using react ). Firebase offers plenty of methods in the front-end for authentication of the user. Where can i find one that fetches it ?

Comment: Have you checked this answer [Verify if a phone number exist in firebase app using firebase cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515508/verify-if-a-phone-number-exist-in-firebase-app-using-firebase-cloud-function) ? This however does required a Cloud Function to securely check this.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615308/how-to-check-if-a-user-already-exists-in-firebase-during-phone-auth: "Right now, the only way to do that is via the Firebase Admin SDK." So it seems like there is no client-side API to do the same. You can wrap the Admin SDK in a Cloud Function to be able to call is from your client-side code.